# Linear regulator with tab at ground

Tags: linear-regulator, pad

I am searching for a linear regulator with tab connected to GND instead of Vout because it would be easier for thermal management. Unfortunately, all linear regulators seem to have their tab connected to output. Is there any linear regulator with tab connected to GND ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: All? Which ones? How many you searched?

Comment: All +ve LDO’s have high side drive only and thus gnd current is from supply not IC. So you must use a mica & grease or thermal conductor/electrical insulator 3M tape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is there any linear regulator with tab connected to GND ?*

All the [78 series](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2307057.pdf?_ga=2.135634161.1310239533.1597146285-282833041.1594297161&_gac=1.256116601.1597404834.CjwKCAjwmrn5BRB2EiwAZgL9oksn3SkmjRHfuVEYIv1Ho4ga5v1ez3IzWo0spTkFu84Fv9q1fTntkxoCSX4QAvD_BwE) have tab connected to ground: -

[image]